# Using PHP to determine trends in a database of user texts

Tags: php

I've read through a number of posts here about algorithms and generalized methods for calculating trends in texts, but I'm in need of a practical, simple example of how to do this using PHP.

[One post that was more helpful than the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859197/finding-trends-in-loads-of-text-data) suggested normalizing each text and then breaking each into an array based on words (after filering out links, usernames, etc), building a large array of each word from each message and then using [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to find which words were the most frequent.  This seems doable, but I don't know if it's the best way. It seems, for example, to favor single-word results rather than phrases ("Barack" and "Obama" rather than "Barack Obama").

Is there a better way to proceed than this? A practical example or pre-existing solution (a script or class) that I might use?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is very difficult to do automatically without first having collected a massive amount of data about words and phrases.

Unless you're willing to spend a huge amount of time, money and continual resources to automate it, I'd either suggest manually creating a list of words that should be counted as a phrase (like if Barack and Obama are adjacent, extract it as Barack Obama), or just forget the whole thing and do it the way the post explains.

There may be external services that can parse data in the way you want, but no doubt they'll come at a hefty price

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't understand why there isn't a simpler solution developed for this yet.  It doesn't need to be the most sophisticated solution (e.g. Twitter's trends) but needs to be something. :/

Comment: Twitter wouldn't be able to do it if they didn't have the enormous amount of text data they get. Everyone talks about 'Barack Obama' and they can pick up on the trend, but the thing with trends is that you need a history of data to back it up and construct your analysis from